# 2 funciones save en un mismo controlador codeigniter 4 - la segunda no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo 2 formularios en el mismo controlador, pero los 2 "save" tienen parametros distintos, el primero ubicado en la página de inicio si funciona correctamente, pero el segundo no me guarda los datos en la base de datos, he estado revisando pero no logro saber si es problema de tener los dos en el mismo controlador o es por otro motivo que desconozco.

MODELO -> UserContact.php

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserContact extends Model{
    protected $table = 'contact';
    protected $primaryKey = 'contact_id';
    protected $allowedFields = ['user_name_contacto','user_email_contacto','user_mensaje_contacto','user_created_at_contacto'];
}
```

Controlador que SI funciona (pagina home)--> Home.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;
use App\Models\UserContact;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        helper(['form']);
        $data = [];
        return view('index', $this->viewData);
    }



    public function save()
    {
        //include helper form
        helper(['form']);

        //set rules validation form
        $rules = [
            'name'  => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]',
            'email' => 'required|valid_email'
        ];

        if ($this->validate($rules)) {
            $model = new UserModel();
            $data = [
                'user_name'  => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_email' => $this->request->getVar('email')
            ];

            // Valores de envío para el método mail()...
            $to      = 'loremipsum@loremipsum.com, loremipsum@loremipsum.com';
            $subject = 'A ' . $data['user_name'] . ' loremipsum';
            $message = $data['user_name'] . ' ha rellenado el formulario de la pagina de inicio || Su correo es:' . $data['user_email'];

            // Si el envío no se ha podido realizar, detiene el código y muestra error...
            if (!mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
                die('El mensaje no se ha enviado');
            }

            $model->save($data);

            return redirect()->to('/{locale}/gracias');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
        }
    }
```

Controlador que no funciona (contacto)--> Home.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\UserModel;
use App\Models\UserContact;

class Home extends BaseController
{
public function contacto()
    {
        helper(['form']);
        $data_contacto = [];
        $locale = $this->request->getLocale();
        return view('contacto', $this->viewData);
    }
     public function saveContacto()
        {
            //include helper form
            helper(['form']);
    
            //set rules validation form
            $rules_contacto = [
                'name_contacto'  => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]',
                'email_contacto' => 'required|valid_email',
                'text_contacto' => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[500]'
            ];
    
            if ($this->validate($rules_contacto)) {
                $model_contacto = new UserModel();
                $data_contacto = [
                    'user_name_contacto'  => $this->request->getVar('name_contacto'),
                    'user_email_contacto' => $this->request->getVar('email_contacto'),
                    'user_mensaje_contacto' => $this->request->getVar('text_contacto'),
                ];
    
                // Valores de envío para el método mail()...
                $to      = 'loremipsum@loremipsum.com';
                $subject = 'A ' . $data_contacto['user_name_contacto'] . ' lorem ipsum';
                $message = $data_contacto['user_name_contacto'] . ' ha rellenado el formulario de contacto || Su correo es:' . $data_contacto['user_email_contacto'] . ' || Mensaje: ' . $data_contacto['user_mensaje_contacto'];
    
                // Si el envío no se ha podido realizar, detiene el código y muestra error...
                if (!mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
                    die('El mensaje no se ha enviado');
                }
    
                $model_contacto->save($data_contacto);
    
                return redirect()->to('/{locale}/gracias');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
            }
        }
}
```

Vista -> contacto.php

```
<!-- entrada de datos -->
                <?php if (isset($validation)) : ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger"><?= $validation->listErrors() ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/saveContacto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name_contacto" class="form-control" id="InputForName" value="<?= set_value('user_name_contacto') ?>" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email_contacto" class="form-control" id="InputForEmail" value="<?= set_value('user_email_contacto') ?>" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="text_contacto" id="FormControlTextarea" value="<?= set_value('user_mensaje_contacto') ?>" placeholder="Introduzca aquí su duda" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="buttonHolder">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block text-center">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <!-- END entrada de datos -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el formulario está validando bien y completa las otras acciones (enviar el correo y redirigirte a la página de agradecimiento), puede ser debido fundamentalmente a tres causas:

1 - La más probable. Estás llamando a un modelo distinto (**UserModel**) al que debes (**UserContact**) cuando declaras la variable *$model_contacto*. Debes cambiarlo:

```
// Eliminar o comentar esta línea
// $model_contacto = new UserModel();

// Reemplazarla por esta
$model_contacto = new UserContact();
```

2 - Las columnas de la base de datos no se corresponden con lo que intentas guardar. Revisa que el nombre de los campos que pasas a *$data_contacto* (controlador) y a *$allowedFields* (modelo) tienen los mismos nombres que la tabla *contact* de tu base de datos.

3 - Tu formulario lleva a la dirección *tudominio.com/saveContacto* y ésta no está registrada. Comprueba que has añadido la dirección al archivo **app/config/Routes.php** y que la línea es algo así:

```
$routes->post('/saveContacto', 'Home::saveContacto');
```

Dicho esto, en cualquier caso y como práctica habitual, lo mejor es que añadas una validación cuando realices la acción de insertar, así podrás comprobar si falla y el porqué:

```
// Reemplazar la línea model_contacto->save(data_contacto) por esto
if ($model_contacto->save($data_contacto) === false) {
    var_dump($model_contacto->errors());
}
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias me funcionó!!!!!! tenia puesto mal algo en la ruta y el controlador se me paso totalmente por alto cambiarlo a user contact.